# How to use shiny input variables in a global variable in flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, flexdashboard

I have a problem that I have to take the select input values and use in a function, but I can't call the function in multiple Renders (plot, print, table) because it's a costly function. With the shiny input, I would like to create a Filtered data and other variables too.
The error method I get is the:

> Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.

This is just a simple example.

````
---
title: "TITLE"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: row
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: flatly
runtime: shiny
---


```{r global, include=FALSE}
require(flexdashboard)
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(year = c("2013", "2014", "2015", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2013", "2014", "2015"),
                 cat = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                 freqA = c(100, 100, 110, 80, 80, 90, 90, 90, 100),
                 freqB = c(50, 50, 55, 40, 40, 45, 45, 45, 50))

plus <- function(a,b){
  return(a + b)
}


```


Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------



```{r}

selectInput("a","select A:", c("freqA","freqB"))
selectInput("b","select B:", c("freqA","freqB"))




```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Itens mais frequentes

```{r}

sum <- plus(df[,input$a], df[input$b])


```

### Chart C

```{r}

```


Column {data-width=650,data-high=10}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Relações

```{r}

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the way the error message says: you can only use `reactives` (such as input elements) in reactive expressions.

This is because every time the input elements change, the output must be rerendered, and you can only do this in `reactive context`.

**Edit:**

1. You can create a `reactive` variable in an R chunk:

The contents will be cached, so it only runs once, even if you will use it in different chunks:

````
```{r}

sum <- reactive( {
  plus(df[,input$a], df[input$b])
})

```
````

2. After this, you can use the reactive expression called `sum` within render functions, such as `renderPrint`:

Note that you can access `reactives` just like functions (i.e.: `sum()`)

````
### Itens mais frequentes

```{r}
renderPrint( {
  sum()
})
```
````

[image]

Comment: The problem is that like i said, i have to store the value of the function or a filtered data like data[year == input$year,] in global variables.

Comment: @augustocarilloferrari edited my answer based on your comment.